# .Net core 2.2 How to get .dll or .exe files digital signature

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the following code to find the digital certificate for an assembly using .net 4.5:

```
            Assembly loaded = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly);
            var module = loaded.GetModules()[0];
            var cert = module.GetSignerCertificate();
            if(cert!=null)
                Console.WriteLine($"Certificate Subject {cert.Subject}");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Certificate not found");
```

However the same check does not work in .net core, what would be the best way to check for the certificate in .net core?

Comment: This API was [dropped](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/99) to break a dependency on the Crypto API. The Crypto API equivalent appears to be [`X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromsignedfile?view=netcore-2.2). The [recommendation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/strong-name-signing.md) is to not use strong names for your own assemblies, in any case.